# how to enable MSI-X support for NIC?

Tags: pci-express, linux-kernel, interrupts

I want to utilize the MSI-X functionality of my NIC but its not getting enabled. As you can see below, MSI-X capability is there but disabled. How to enable this?

```
    # lspci -v
00:00.0 PCI bridge: Synopsys, Inc. Device abcd (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 306
        Memory at 01000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        Memory behind bridge: 01100000-012fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 01300000-013fffff
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 01400000 [disabled] [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport

01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 307
        Memory at 01100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Memory at 01200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        [virtual] Expansion ROM at 01300000 [disabled] [size=1M]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] MSI-X: Enable- Count=5 Masked-
        Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 6c-b3-11-ff-ff-52-02-a1
        Capabilities: [1a0] Transaction Processing Hints
        Kernel driver in use: igb
        Kernel modules: igb
```

Comment: MSI-X is supported in PCI 3.0 only.

Comment: I checked on another PC which has PCI bridges of version 2.3. The same NIC along with same driver is supporting MSI-X capability there.

Comment: I have checked the driver code and pci_enable_msix function is giving error. Debugging further in pcie host controller driver for PCI_CAP_ID_MSIX type it is giving the error.Any idea why this is happenening?